# VM won't bring up using homestead up

Tags: laravel-5, virtual-machine, homestead

I have no issue running vm's using `homestead up` but last week I just updated to the latest Windows 10 update and now when I run the command it gives me

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "c8da3222-7052-452a-b590-ff7144b50c9e", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'homestead-7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\magal\VirtualBox VMs\homestead-7\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

Been searching the web for a solution but got no luck.

> Box Version : 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Without more info the only advice is to run `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` If you still have issues after that, consider opening a new issue on https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/new

Comment: I'm not sure also what causes the issue. Yes thanks for the link man!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed after upgrading my Virtualbox to `5.2`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, I installed everything as **ADMINISTRATOR** and only the following configuration worked for me:

**Vagrant 1.9.2** : [Download Vagrant 1.9.2](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.2/)

**Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.30** : [Download Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.30](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.30/)

For older versions of *VirtualBox*, the virtual machine has terminated unexpectedly.
For newer versions of *VirtualBox*, the host-only adapter cannot be created.

When you upgrade or downgrade, make sure that you **permanently delete (Shift + Delete)** the following folders from *C:\Users\your-user* : **.vagrant**, **.VirtualBox** and **Virtual VM Machines**. When using `vagrant up`, these folders will be created again.

After each program install and uninstall, make sure to restart your computer. Old files from VirtualMachine and Vagrant are persistent until the OS boots up again.